# Ubuntu on DigitalOcean does not use the latest kernel

Tags: grub2, kernel

On a digialocean's VPS, I have some linux kernel installed. This is the result when I do `sudo update-grub` :

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.2-031602-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.2-031602-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-37-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-36-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-36-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-34-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-33-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-33-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-27-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-27-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-lowlatency
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
```

Voici la version du kernel utilisée :

```
$ uname -r
3.8.0-38-generic
```

I tried to do an update and an upgrade, I also tried to this

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.0-24 linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
```

This cause this issue :

```
$ sudo depmod
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.8.0-38-generic: No such file or directory
```

Do you have a solution ?
    depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.  I followed [this solution](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-update-a-digitalocean-server-s-kernel). I had to change the kernel version in the control panel and reboot through the control panel.